# Can't access User Accounts in ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, user-management

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS as a dualboot next to windows. Everything is working fine and i must say i like it. But i have one problem, I can't access the User Accounts. By clicking on User Accounts the screen goes black and grey and nothing happens. I can only use the X to close the window. I also tried to access it using the terminal window but the same negative result. How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue on an old intel mac mini dual booting 14.04 LTS but just solved it after reading this:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gst-plugins-good1.0/+bug/1242367

Seems my issue was to do with an Empia USB TV capture card with em2860 as chip ID. Unplugging the card was enough to fix the blacked-out hanging user accounts window! Kernel wierdness beyond my comprehension and expertise apparently going on...